# setIconTextGap for labels with centered alignment

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jlabel

I need to add an icon to a table header which is a JLabel.

When the text is aligned on the left hand side, it's working fine.

However, when the text is centered, the call to setIconTextGap() is somehow not considered. This has the effect, that the icon is also placed in the center of the label:

[image]

Is this not working in general, or did I miss something?

I'm working with Java 6 (cannot change that fact).

I have created a SSCCE below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        IconLabel label1 = new IconLabel("test text left", new TableArrowIcon(TableArrowIcon.TableArrowDirection.NORTH), SwingConstants.LEFT);
        IconLabel label2 = new IconLabel("test text center", new TableArrowIcon(TableArrowIcon.TableArrowDirection.NORTH), SwingConstants.CENTER);

        Object[][] data = {
                {"Speed reading", 20, true },
                {"Joe", "Brown", "Pool", 10, false }
        };

        String[] columnNames = { "test", "test" };

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        final JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 70));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        label2.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        TableColumn column1 = new TableColumn();
        TableColumn column2 = new TableColumn();
        column1.setHeaderRenderer(label1);
        column2.setHeaderRenderer(label2);
        table.addColumn(column1);
        table.addColumn(column2);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        panel.add(scrollPane);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(1);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static class IconLabel extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer {

        private final Icon icon;
        private final int alignment;

        public IconLabel(String text, Icon icon, int alignment) {
            super(text);
            this.icon = icon;
            setIcon(icon);
            setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50, 20));
            this.alignment = alignment;
        }

        @Override
        public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            int textWidth = getFontMetrics(getFont()).stringWidth(getText());
            Insets insets = getInsets();
            int iconTextGap = width - textWidth - icon.getIconWidth() - insets.left - insets.right -     3;
            setIconTextGap(iconTextGap);
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean     isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            setHorizontalTextPosition(alignment);
            return this;
        }
    }

    public static class TableArrowIcon implements Icon {

        public enum TableArrowDirection {
            NORTH() {
                @Override
                public void drawArrow(Graphics2D g, int controlSize, int x, int y) {
                    g.drawLine(x + 3, y + (controlSize - 10), x + 7, y + (controlSize - 14));
                    g.drawLine(x + 7, y + (controlSize - 14), x + (controlSize - 9), y + (controlSize     - 10));
                }
            };
            public abstract void drawArrow(Graphics2D g, int controlSize, int x, int y);
        }

        private final TableArrowDirection direction;



        public TableArrowIcon(TableArrowDirection direction) {
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintIcon(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y) {
            g.setColor(Color.darkGray);

            int controlSize = 20;
            ((Graphics2D) g).setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,     RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
            direction.drawArrow((Graphics2D) g, controlSize, x, y);

        }

        @Override
        public int getIconWidth() {
            return 14;
        }

        @Override
        public int getIconHeight() {
            return 14;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a JPanel as the render and add two labels to the panel. One for the text and the other for the Icon.
2. You can use a BorderLayout for the panel.
3. Add the text label to the CENTER and the Icon to the LINE_END.
4. You will then need a parameter for the renderer to indicate if the text should be left justified or centered. This should be set in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for this, but this is not going to work properly, as the text will not be centrally aligned but only within its label. That means that the text alignment will be the icon size off :)

Comment: @Fish-Guts Then use a JPanel with a FlowLayout. The point is be creative and use the appropriate layout manager to achieve your desired layout. Your question does not clearly explain what you are attempting to do, so the suggestion can't be specific either. Also, it should not take you a month to reply when people take the time to help.